# Getting "undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass" error when injecting array with hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashtable, inject

This is my first time using Ruby, and I need to use the inject method to create a hash from a given array. This code pretty closely mirrors several tutorials I've found, but get an `` undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass `` error when executing. Am I missing anything here?

```
def int_hash()
    [[:key1, "value1"], [:key2, "value2"]].inject({}) do |hash, element|
            hash[element.first] = element.last
            puts hash
    end
end

int_hash()
```

Comment: Though it's preferable to use [Hash#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) or [Hash::\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), you might consider writing what you have as  `...do |hash, (k, v)| hash[k] = v...` This makes use of [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition), which is a powerful and useful language feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `puts` is the last statement in the block and it returns `nil`, `nil` is returned causing the accumulator `hash` to be `nil` in the second iteration. You should return the hash. And you should pass the array as an argument to the `inj_hash` method to make it reusable.

```
def inj_hash(arr)
  arr.inject({}) do |hash, element|
    hash[element.first] = element.last
    hash
  end
end

inj_hash([[:key1, "value1"], [:key2, "value2"]])
#=> {:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2"}
```

The simplest solution to create a hash from an array of key-value pairs is to use [`Hash::[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

```
arr = [[:key1, "value1"], [:key2, "value2"]]
Hash[arr]
#=> {:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2"}
```

Comment: Or switch to `Hash#merge!` (`[[:key1, "value1"], [:key2, "value2"]].inject({}) { |hash, element| hash.merge!(element.first => element.last) }`) or even `Array#to_h` (`[[:key1, "value1"], [:key2, "value2"]].to_h`). But this looks like an `Enumerable#inject` exercise so your first one of my `merge!` version are probably the most appropriate.

Comment: If you want debug output, you can use `p hash`. As opposed to `puts` it returns the passed argument(s).